# How to calculate recursive sum of childs for their parents in json formated data through jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to calculate recursive sum of childs for their parents in json formatted data through jQuery or javascript. 
Suppose I have a data in json format like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "AccountName": "a",
        "ParentID": "",
        "OpeningDebit": 0,
        "OpeningCredit": 0
    }, {
        "ID": "2",
        "AccountName": "b",
        "ParentID": "1",
        "OpeningDebit": 0,
        "OpeningCredit": 0
    }, {
        "ID": "3",
        "AccountName": "c",
        "ParentID": "2",
        "OpeningDebit": 100,
        "OpeningCredit": 200
    }]
}
```

I want to calculate all the childs sum for their parent through recursive jQuery or javascript function like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "AccountName": "a",
        "ParentID": "",
        "OpeningDebit": 100,
        "OpeningCredit": 200
    }, {
        "ID": "2",
        "AccountName": "b",
        "ParentID": "1",
        "OpeningDebit": 100,
        "OpeningCredit": 200
    }, {
        "ID": "3",
        "AccountName": "c",
        "ParentID": "2",
        "OpeningDebit": 100,
        "OpeningCredit": 200
    }]
}
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any errors in the console? Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: From your example, I don't see anything recursive, and I also don't see a difference between the two bits of code. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk I think what they're saying is that there's a chain where 1 is the parent of 2 is the parent of 3. 3 has a `debit` of `100` and `credit` of `200`, and so its parent, `2`, also has that same debit/credit. In turn, ITS parent `1` also takes on that credit/debit.

Comment: this is hierarchical data with parent child relationship , i dont have any example and working ,

Comment: @IceMetalPunk exactly .... throught javascript or jquery function

Answer (score 0):

Try a recursive reduce:

```
function recurseSum(element, key) {
  const children = data.filter(child => child.parentID === element.ID);
  if (children.length <= 0) {
    element['sum' + key] = element[key];
    return element[key];
  }
  element['sum' + key] = element[key] + chidlren.reduce((sum, child) => {
    return sum + recurseSum(child, key);
  }, 0);
  return element['sum' + key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks , let me try